# How should I structure a Go module so as to be able to run it easily and import internal packages?

Tags: go

I'm just discovering Go. When I started looking at it last week, I found out GOPATH and how Go apparently is very opinionated about what directories you store your code in. So I cursed Google's name and decided Go wasn't for me, then recently heard about Go modules and how apparently they resolve this very issue.

The trouble is that information online on how to structure a module-based Go project appears to be very scarce. I'm having trouble figuring out how to lay out my code and what to call the packages in order to get imports working. I've tried various things and looked at examples but no matter what I do, I get "unknown import path" errors.

Basically I want to have a directory with, say, `main.go` and `library.go`, maybe with `library.go` in a subdirectory. I want to be able to write `import library` or something similar in `main.go` and be able to access members of `library.go`. I also want to be able to run the code by typing `go run main.go`. Is this achievable?

Comment: That's not only achievable, it's the definition of a typical Go program. Take a look at any Go project using modules for examples. There is no "best way" to structure a project. If you're having a specific problem, please post about that problem and include the relevant code.

Comment: @Adrian My problem is that I don't know where to begin and *can't find* any example code. [The official tutorial](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) only talks about *external* dependencies. [This article](https://vsupalov.com/go-folder-structure/) seems to suggest that if I just use the cmd/internal style directory structure and then type `go run [my main file]` it should work, but that didn't work. Meanwhile, googling the problems leads to many many forum threads with people complaining about how this is hard to do and suggesting workarounds involving `replace`.

Comment: I *do not have* a specific problem and example code because *I am a beginner and have no idea what I'm doing*. I have of course tried a lot of things, but I'm not going to post 10 `.go` files worth of dead ends in here just to show I tried. All I would need is a simple two-file example project like I suggested  complete with directory structure and what `go run` command to use.

Answer (score 2):

It is confusing and the documentation assumes a level of familiarity with Golang. I've been trying to understand Modules recently.

#### The previous|current way without Modules:

```sh
WORKDIR=[[PATH-TO-YOUR-WORKING-DIRECTORY]]

mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}/go
export GOPATH=${WORKDIR}/go
export PATH=${GOPATH}/bin:${PATH}

mkdir -p {${WORKDIR}/go/src/foo, ${WORKDIR}/go/src/foo/bar}
```

Then create `${WORKDIR}/go/src/foo/bar/library.go`:

```
package bar

func Something() (string) {
    return "Hello Freddie"
}
```

Then create `${WORKDIR}/go/src/foo/main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "foo/bar"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%s", bar.Something())
}
```

You'll have a structure like this:

```
.
└── go
    └── src
        └── foo
            ├── bar
            │   └── library.go
            └── main.go
```

Then you may run this either of the following ways:

```sh
GO111MODULE=off go run ${WORKDIR}/go/src/main.go
Hello Freddie!

cd ${WORKDIR}/go/src/
GO111MODULE=off go run main.go
Hello Freddie!

GO111MODULE=off go run foo
Hello Freddie!
```

#### The new (!) way with Modules:

Assuming you've done the above!

You don't need to do this step but this is the new best practice. We're moving our sources outside of `${GOPATH}`. `${GOPATH}` is still used to store our versioned packages. **NB** In this trivial example, we're not using external packages so `${GOPATH}` remains empty.

```sh
mv ${WORKDIR}/go/src/foo ${WORKDIR}
rm ${WORKDIR}/go/src
```

You should a structure like this:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── library.go
│   └── main.go
└── go
```

**NB** Our sources are now outside of `${GOPATH}`

```sh
cd ${WORKDIR}/foo

GO111MODULE=on go mod init foo
more go.mod
module foo

go 1.12

GO111MODULE=on go run foo
Hello Freddie!

GO111MODULE=on go run main.go
Hello Freddie!
```

#### For Completeness

To show the difference with external packages:

No Modules pulls the latest version of the package into `${GOPATH}/src`:

```sh
GO111MODULE=off go get github.com/golang/glog

.
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── library.go
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum
│   └── main.go
└── go
    └── src
        └── github.com
            └── golang
                └── glog
                    ├── glog_file.go
                    ├── glog.go
                    ├── glog_test.go
                    ├── LICENSE
                    └── README
```

Versus using Modules, pulls a specific version (or versions) of the package into `${GOPATH}/pkg`:

```
GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/golang/glog

.
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── library.go
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── go.sum
│   └── main.go
└── go
    └── pkg
        ├── linux_amd64
        │   └── github.com
        │       └── golang
        │           └── glog.a
        └── mod
            ├── cache
            │   ├── download
            │   │   └── github.com
            │   │       └── golang
            │   │           └── glog
            └── github.com
                └── golang
                    └── glog@v0.0.0-20160126235308-23def4e6c14b
                        ├── glog_file.go
                        ├── glog.go
                        ├── glog_test.go
                        ├── LICENSE
                        └── README
```

#### Notes

- Our file names are somewhat arbitrary. You said `library.go` so I've used that and conventionally, files are named after their content.
- Our directory names are important. Go uses directory names to help find packages. So, even though `library.go` could have been called `freddie.go` or `something.go`, it's important that it be `package bar` and in a directory called `bar`.
- An exception to these rules is that `main.go` is conventionally where `func main() {...}` is defined and `func main() {...}` must be in a package called `main`. So, even though the directory is called `foo`, because we want a `main` function, we name the file `main.go` and it must be `package main`.
- In package `bar`, it's important that `Something` be initially capitalized (`S`). This exports the function from the `bar` package so that it may be used by other packages. If the function's name were lowercase (`something`), the function is only available to other functions within the `bar` package.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to replicate your working example. I'll have to look at it more closely tomorrow. I think probably the big thing that tripped me up is that the file name doesn't matter. Coming from Python, it was just obvious to me that of *course* the file name has to appear in your import statement.

Comment: I'm glad it worked and hope it help! Golang is similar to Java and .NET in that the directory structure reflects the package structure not the file names. The good news is that, if this make sense, you've pretty much cracked package management in Golang.